# Convergence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be random variables (both with mean zero and variance one). I read a paper that proves $\mathbb{E}[(X_n+Y_n)^2]\rightarrow 0$ and since it was known that $Y_n\rightarrow N(0,1)$ (in distribution), then we get $X_n\rightarrow N(0,1)$ in distribution, but I do not see how they get that last implication.

Comment: Did the paper assume independence also?  Because otherwise the steps are incorrect.

Comment: @Paul Huh? $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did, without an independence assumption, it is not true in general that $E[(X_n+Y_n)^2] \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Paul You misread the question. That $E((X_n+Y_n)^2)\to0$ is a hypothesis. (Fortunately--since if $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent, both with mean zero and variance one, then $E((X_n+Y_n)^2)\to0$ is *impossible*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $X_n=-Y_n+X_n+Y_n$. Since $-Y_n\to N(0,1)$ and $X_n+Y_n$ goes to $0$ in probability, we get the wanted conclusion.

Comment: Got it. You use Markov's to prove $X_n+Y_n$ goes to 0 in probability.